# How to duplicate icons

Tags: app-icons

I am using Android 6.0.1 on a Samsung J7.
I have an icon in my home screen that is a shortcut to an app in [Parallel Space－Multi Accounts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl). I want to duplicate it.
(I have created it from within Parallel Space, but it does not allow for creating another such icon.)

**How can it be done?**

Note that it is not a direct shortcut to an App, so I cannot hit "+" in the folder I want to get the duplicate.
[This](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m7/282431-creating-duplicate-icon-home-screen.html) appears to deal with such case, so it would not be useful.

Comment: @beeshyams Guess sancho is less interested in having a picture, but rather wants the same "instance" of the app be referenced from e.g. another homescreen. For some background: *Parallel space* allows you to use the same app with different accounts/settings/whatever, basically by putting it into separate "sandboxes" each with its own `/data/data/*` etc.

Comment: @Izzy - That is correct.